# Unresolved Function or Method push() FLEX ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, intellij-idea, flex4.6

After a recent reinstallation of my computer I have encoutered a very frustrating and strange issue with JetBrains IntelliJ.

I have this line of code

`this.path_.data.push(r.left, r.top, r.right, r.top, r.right, r.bottom, r.left, r.bottom);`

And similar ones around my project.

`path_ = new GraphicsPath(GraphicsUtil.QUAD_COMMANDS, new Vector.<Number>());`

data inside of path_ is a `Vector.<Number>` but for some reason I am unable to use the function `native AS3 function push(... rest):uint;` on it. It just shows me [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F84G4.png)

I have tried to find a solution to this issue for the past 6 hours and haven't found anything so far... Hoping anyone here might be able to give some assistance with this issue.

Note: This has never happened to me in the past.

I have looked into the declaration of `push()` and it points to my `library.swf` for everything except the code that uses GraphicsPath.data... That file seem to point to `ECMAScript.js2` which doesn't contain anything for Vector Objects at all.

Comment: Please consider swapping the creation of data vector and creation of `GraphicsPath`. It's possible that in the new Flash player `GraphicsPath.data` is read only, or is a "void*" type instead of array type. It also might be a bug in IntelliJ IDEA, ask them directly.

Comment: @Vesper Yes But... I never had this problem before I reinstalled my computer. I was running same version of Intellij, Same source code and didn't have this recognition problem. No one I asked who is working with same or similar sources have this problem either... At first I thought it was a SDK problem but after going through various peoples SDKs there's no real difference to cause it...

The GraphicsPath data variable is this

`native public var data:Vector.<Number>;`

Comment: Maybe the file is "updated" without your notice. Check if you can compare your `ECMAscript.js2` with someone else's file, maybe the whole tree of ECMAscript IDE respource part.

Comment: @Vesper But the thing is... It's not supposed to look inside of ECMAScript for the declaration for Vector Object. So because there is no Vector Object base inside of ECMAScript it shouldn't be moving into that file... It should be moving to the Library.swf that is part of the FLEX SDKs playergloblal.swc

Comment: I'd check both the SDK version linked and the module configuration in the project settings ... looks like you're using a javascript module instead of a flash module